# Make two divs shift left/right from browser end

Tags: jquery, html, css

I´ve been fiddling with this for quite a long time now, and I hope you can help.
What I am trying to achieve, is:

I have two divs, a red and a blue one. The red is default visible, and the blue is hidden. Their heights differ, but width is the same. If you click the red div it should slide to the left side and "out of the browser window". Meanwhile the blue div should come from the right browser side and slide in to the space where the red was placed before. If you then click the blue div, the animation should "reverse".

Seems simple, but I cant figure it out. Ive tried with jQuery slide and width, and jQuery UI´s slide. The problem is often css positioning. Either the divs 'jumps' in in place so the animation is bulky. If I use css positioning absolute/relative, it isnt possible to set the width so they slide all the way out to the browsers right/left ends. Instead, the are getting cut off at their respective widths.

This image illustrates what I would like to achieve.

Really hope you can help :)[image: illustration]

Comment: please show jquery code you have so far and markup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something very simple like this:

```
(function($){
    $(function() {
        var red = $('#red'),
            blue = $('#blue');

        red.click(function() {
            red.stop().animate({
                left: '-' + 0 - red.width() + 'px'
            }, 400);
            blue.stop().animate({
                left: '50%'
            }, 400);
        });

        blue.click(function() {
            blue.stop().animate({
                left: '150%'
            }, 400);
            red.stop().animate({
                left: '50%'
            }, 400);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFSfM/)

Another idea would be to create a div with overflow hidden which you can animte in scrollLeft

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer.
I still have some problems with positioning though. Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uJ2W8/1/

I would like to make the "red and blue bars" align to the top layout where the logo and text is. Regarding of screen size and resolution.
This is kind of hard when using absolute and relative :(

Comment: I think I got it working now. I just need to find halft the width of the page, and subtract the bars length. Then I have their placement. 
But its kind of messy, so guess I gotta clean it up a little...
Anyways, thanks for your great help! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://bxslider.com/) is a simple to implement jQuery Slider. Hope it helps. As a tip, you can hide your next/prev buttons and the pager and for 'next' functionality you use a jQuery selector that goes to your image.